# why large messages produced and published to rabbitmq by bunny in ruby are encoded into base64

Tags: ruby, json, rabbitmq, bunny

I'm using bunny gem to publish messages, which are json string, to the rabbitmq server. 
The code are as followed:

```
def send_rabbitmq value
    conn = Bunny.new(:host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", :vhost => "/", :user => "abc", :password =>"123")
    conn.start

    ch = conn.create_channel
    ch.basic_publish( value ,"exchange.x", "routing.key", :payload_encoding => "string")
    sleep 1.0
end
```

However, what I get from the rabbitmq server are just messy string which are encoded by `base64`. The message **(value in the code)** I publish is bigger than 90000 size. I figure it out by copying all the string into a encoding tool and decode the messy string by `base64`, which are just the data I sent, but only a part of them. It looks like the data published is truncated, with the absence of bracket, comma or some key/values.

So, here is my question, I know it's not suggested to publish huge message to rabbitmq, but how come the data is encoded into base64 and why they are truncated.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: I publish 90 MiB messages every 5 minutes to 20-30 consumers over RabbitMQ. There have been no issues so far.

Comment: What is the *type* of `value`? Is it a String? AMQP itself uses a binary protocol for the body, so anything can go in. If the value you're sending is not a String, I don't know how it would be serialized.